# Setting up the expected value for $x_t=\sin(2\pi U t)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

We have the series $x_t=\sin(2\pi U t)$ where $t=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $U$ is uniform on the interval $(0,1)$. I have to find the expected value of $x_t$. I always thought that if $X$ is a continuous random variable then $$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_x(x) \, dx.$$ In this case I was thinking it be $$E(x_t)=\int_0^1 u\sin(2\pi U t) \, du$$ rather than $$E(x_t)=\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi U t) \, du.$$ I think the first way is correct, but I don't see why the second way would be correct since we are trying to vary $U$. I am not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U is uniformly distributed hence $f_u \,du = 1 \, du$. The function you are taking the expected value of is $x_t (U) = \sin(2\pi Ut)$. Thus, you want $\Bbb E_U[x_t]$ = $\int_0^1 x_t f_u \,du$ = $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi Ut)\cdot 1\, du$

For further information, look up the box muller method for simulating normal random variables. It's very similar.

Comment: Essentially, you want to take the expectation in the U measure...

Comment: Thanks I completely understand now.

Comment: Basically if we let $g(U)=sin(2pi U t)$, then $E(g(U))=\int_{0}^{1} f_U (u) g(U) du$. That is how I see it.

Comment: @JamieLannister : You are as confused as is the original poster about when to use capital $U$ and when to use lower-case $U$.  If capital $U$ is a random variable supported on the interval $[0,1]$ then $\operatorname{E}(g(U)) = \int_0^1 u f_U(u)\,du$.  Notice which ones are capitals and which are not.  The bound variable with respect to which you integrate is in lower case and the subscript is capital.  This distinction makes it possible to understand such things as $f_U(0.7)$ or $\Pr(U\le u)$.  You should have $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi ut)\cdot 1\,du$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user60887 : The same applies to you. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy, who cares? Answer's right... and the original idea is still in tact.

Comment: @JamieLannister : In fact, the very thing I am pointing out makes it possible to solve problems in cases where it would otherwise not be possible. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @JamieLannister : It seems you don't understand that errors and failures to understand and solve problems can result from neglect of this sort of thing. So you may claim to have found this one problem in which that does not happen.  You'll notice I have a reputation on math.stackexchange.com that is more than 100,000, and that did not result from an inability to solve problems, as you suggested in a comment that you have since deleted. ${}\qquad{}$